# When to use pug/jade or html5 with server-side programming?

Tags: node.js, pug, serverside-javascript, web-development-server

I am very eager to learn in the area of web-development and lately I started learning server-side programming after doing front-end web-development first.

Now it appeared to me that there are some templating languages such as jade/pug. However I cannot seem to fully understand the concept/purpose of these languages.

- Do you first create your front-end part using html5 and css and then
  convert this html to pug in order to use it for server-side
  programming?
- if so, why not just use html?
- Or do you actually create your webpages using pug from scratch?

I do understand that a lot of information can be found with a quick google search. Therefore I want to emphasize that I actually did a lot of searching already. However, I cannot seem to fully grasp the concept or maybe I don't ask the right questions.
Therefore, I would really appreciate it if someone could explain what the exact role of these templating languages is in web development so that I understand the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

I am using pug for three main reasons:

- less to write (CSS selector like syntax, no closing tags)
- better readability because you are basically writing the DOM instead of tags
- the "extends" functionality to avoid duplicate code

Other (obvious) reasons are the possibility to use variables, loops, if-statements or even function calls to format or transform data in any possible way.

I usually create a layout.pug file containing everything that is contained in every page plus a `block main` and other views that `extends layout`. Depending on the project I also use a `block head` and `block script` to allow specific pages to inject additional stylesheets or scripts.

I got used to only writing pug code combined with stylus which concept is quite similar, so having to write plain HTML or CSS from time to time even got annoying.

Pug is also great in combination with bootstrap and/or Angular so I see no reason not to use it.